# ASP.NET MVC and Visual Studio 2013: Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

From time to time I get "Compilation Error" CS0042 yellow page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwfip.png

[image: Compilation Error yellow page]

It happens when I change something (i.e. .cshtml file code) when my application is running. In VS 2012 it caused no problems. Some of my co-workers using VS 2013 have the same issue. Why App_GlobalResources.PDB file causes the problem?

Anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Web.config file remove attribute
`optimizeCompilations="true"` 
 (`from section <compilation />`)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog post](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-net-2003-c-compile-error-cs0042/), the problem is very much similar with yours. Please try the following things mentioned in the post:

> 1. Exit VS.NET, restart VS.NET and reopen project
> 2. Change project from Debug Build to Release Build and visa-versa.
> 3. Remove all Enums from classes and just use in the namespace
> 4. Ensure all DLL projects have  ‘CopyLocal’ set to true AND references
>      to these DLL’s be a Project Reference and not simple a DLL
>      reference.

If it's not working, it should be a bug presented in the Visual Studio 2013 then.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't get this part: "Remove all Enums from classes and just use in the namespace"

Comment: I think that just means to remove all the enum types out of the class and put them into namespace instead

Comment: I don't have any enum types in classes.

Comment: Well then skip that part